# How to adjust parenthesis thickness without changing the font?

Tags: brackets, kpfonts, parentheses

I use `kpfonts`, and equations like `\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)` or`\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]` produce thick parentheses etc. that look very heavy compared to the rest of the text.

Is it possible to make them to be of the same thickness as the non-adaptive version `[ ] ( )`?

Example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
[x_j] \left[x_j\right] \left(\frac{1}{y_j}\right) \text{(some text for comparison)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tex has no control over this at all, the design of the larger parenthesis, just as the design of the smaller ones is in the hands of the font designer. Assuming the extended delimiters are coming from a suitable font. If you had included an example document the font usage could be debugged.

Comment: I've added a picture to show what I mean. So, the only possibility is to import these delimiters from another font?

Comment: yes, but also not use left/right so much (I would never use it with `x_j` for example).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, they are still too thick for fractions, matrices etc.

Comment: That is the design of font designer chose, you are free to choose another font by another designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

[image]

The kpfonts have a lighter weight extension font so you can copy the declarations of `omxjkp.fd` so they use the font from `omxjkpl.fd`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\ProvidesFile{omxjkpl.fd}
    [2006/08/15 v1.0]

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{jkp}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{jkp}{m}{n}{
   <-> jkplex%
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{jkp}{bx}{n}{
   <-> jkplbex%
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{jkp}{l}{n}{<->ssub * jkpl/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{jkp}{b}{n}{<->ssub * jkpl/bx/n}{}



\begin{document}

\[
(A)\left(A_j\right)\left(\frac{B}{C}\right)
  \left(\frac{\frac{D_a^2}{D_b}}{\frac{E_x}{E_y}}\right)
\quad
[A]\left[A_j\right]\left[\frac{B}{C}\right]
  \left[\frac{\frac{D_a^2}{D_b}}{\frac{E_x}{E_y}}\right]
\quad
\sum_0^nx^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! This works. Could you explain what  `<-> jkplbex%` and `<->ssub * jkpl/m/n` mean?

Comment: @homocomputeris that is standard latex syntax for loading (or for ssub substituting) a font, look in any `.fd` file or the latex companion. The first says at any size load `jkplbex.tfm` suitable scaled, and the second says at every size substitute the non-bold font that you would get for a request for jkpl/m/n instead of jkplbx/n

Answer (score 3):

I can't really recommend this approach except for small documents, because it is labor intensive.  It requires you to

1. change syntax from `\left...\right` to `\scaleleftright[]{}{}{}`
2. customize the max-width (optional argument) parameter for each particular case
3. employ the `\big`...`\Bigg` approach to get the best appearance
4. It requires the occasional use of `\vphantom`s to get vertical symmetry about the math axis.

The method uses the optional argument of `\scaleleftright` to horizontally compress the glyphs to be no larger than the specified max-width.

The proper solution is to find a font that best suits, or else manually import just a new set of delimiters into the font.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts,scalerel}
\begin{document}

\[
(A)\left(A_j\right)\left(\frac{B}{C}\right)
  \left(\frac{\frac{D_a^2}{D_b}}{\frac{E_x}{E_y}}\right)
\quad
[A]\left[A_j\right]\left[\frac{B}{C}\right]
  \left[\frac{\frac{D_a^2}{D_b}}{\frac{E_x}{E_y}}\right]
\]
\[
(A)\,\scaleleftright[3.1pt]{\bigl(}{A_j^{\vphantom{f}}}{\bigr)}\,
  \scaleleftright[2.8pt]{\biggl(}{\frac{B}{C}}{\biggr)}\,
  \scaleleftright[3.1pt]{\Biggl(}{\frac{\frac{D_a^2}{D_b}}{\frac{E_x}{E_y}}}{\Biggr)}
  \quad
[A]\,\scaleleftright[2.5pt]{\bigl[}{A_j^{\vphantom{f}}}{\bigr]}\,
  \scaleleftright[2.8pt]{\biggl[}{\frac{B}{C}}{\biggr]}\,
  \scaleleftright[3.1pt]{\Biggl[}{\frac{\frac{D_a^2}{D_b}}{\frac{E_x}{E_y}}}{\biggr]}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Alternate syntax of `\xleft[]{}...\xright[]{}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts,scalerel}
\newcommand\xleft[2][99pt]{\mathopen{\scalerel*[#1]{#2}{#2}}}
\newcommand\xright[2][99pt]{\mathclose{\scalerel*[#1]{#2}{#2}}}
\begin{document}

\[
(A)\left(A_j\right)\left(\frac{B}{C}\right)
\quad
[A]\left[A_j\right]\left[\frac{B}{C}\right]
\]
\[
(A)\,\xleft[3.1pt]{\bigl(}A_j\xright[3.1pt]{\bigr)}\,
  \xleft[2.8pt]{\Bigl(}\frac{B}{C}\xright[2.8pt]{\Bigr)}\,
  \quad
[A]\,\xleft[2.4pt]{\bigl[}A_j\xright[2.4pt]{\bigr]}\,
  \xleft[2.8pt]{\Bigl[}\frac{B}{C}\xright[2.8pt]{\Bigr]}\,
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is, obviously, a solution and looks much better. I'm afraid, it is not suitable for a 100-page document.

Comment: A follow up question: how to find the delimiters definitions to import? This question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font/ doesn't clarify much for me. For example, I like `palatino`/`mathpazo`/`newpx*` brackets.

Comment: @homocomputeris  I think David's answer takes this approach.